# How to enable Virtual Host on Xampp for Laravel 5.8

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost, laravel-5.8

I have problem with creating virtual host. I am using Windows 7 x64 Professional.
When i try click on any admin menu dashboard got this error:
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.6

And in file C:\xampp-x64-7.3.6-1-VC15\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf I have this:

    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp-x64-7.3.6-1-VC15\htdocs\gametrade150.lt\public"
    ServerName gametrade150.lt

And of course I have restared my Apache server after adding this lines in those files.

Comment: Did you uncomment this `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in httpd.conf file ?

Comment: Yes, uncomment this file.